# Is it possible to replace characters only within selected a group?

Tags: regex, pcre

Consider: `word1.word2.worda-wordb-wordc.ext`

Is there a regular expression capture and replace string that can be used to obtain as result: `worda wordb wordc` using perl compatible regular expressions?

I know you can capture the group of words a,b,c with: `/.+?\..+?\.(.+?)\.ext$/$1/`, but I don't know how to additionally replace dash (`-`) characters by space ( ) characters only within that group.

---

you can assume that:

- word groups are separated by period `.`
- words within a group are separated by dash `-`
- words are made up of alphanumeric characters `[A-Za-z0-9]`

looking for a one line `/regex/replace/`, not a script.

Comment: So you want to take the string `word1.word2.worda-wordb-wordc.ext` and get as result the string `worda wordb wordc`?

Comment: @TLP yes and in one string like: `/regex/replace/`. and you can assume that word groups are separated by period `.` and that words within a group are separated by dash `-`, and that words are made up of alphanumeric characters `[A-Za-z0-9]` and nothing else.

Comment: btw perhaps i should of mentioned, i'm not looking for a perl script, just a one line `/regex/replace/` if it is possible, else just let me know it can't be done, and requires a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex search-replace:

```bash
(?:^(?:[^.\n]+\.)*?(?=[^.\n]+\.ext$)|(?!^)\G)([^\n-]+)-(?:([^\n.-]+)\..+)?
```

And replace it with:

```
$1 $2
```

**Output:**

```
worda wordb wordc
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN2922/8)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `^`: Start
  - `(?:[^.\n]+\.)*?`: Match 1+ non-dot strings followed by a dot. Repeat this group 0 or more times (lazy match)
  - `(?=[^.\n]+\.ext$)`: Must be followed by a `<anything-but-dot.ext>` and end position
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: Start the next match from end of the previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `[^\n-]+`: Match and capture a non-hyphen substring in capture group #1
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `-`: Match a `-`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `([^\n.-]+)`: Match and capture non-dot, non-hyphen substring in capture group #2
  - `\.`: Match a dot
  - `.+`: Followed by extension
- `)?`: End non-capture group, `?` makes this an optional match

PS: You can remove `\n` everywhere from above regex when matching a single line input.

Comment: Hey, what if now the format was: `word1a-word1b-word1c.word2a-word2b-word2c.word3a-word3b-word3c.ext` or at least `word1.word2a-word2b-word2c.word3a-word3b-word3c.ext` (you can also remove `.ext` from the end if that makes it easier), and we still just wanted: `word3a word3b word3c` ? I've been trying now for almost an hour, I just can't seem to get it. without global flag it can't replace the dash `-` with spaces, and with global it can't grab only the words of the 3rd group because the pattern repeats itself in the 1st and 2nd group of words. Is it even possible ?

Comment: wow, spot on. ok last one i promise, is it possible to have an arbitrary amount of dash separated words in each group ? and still extract only the words of the 3rd group `word3a word3b word3c ...` ? or is it impossible ?

Comment: i mean like a format: `wa1-wa2-wa3-waN.wb1-wb2-wb3-wbN.wc1-wc2-wc3-wcN.ext`, is it possible to get just `wc1 wc2 wc3 ... wcN` no matter how many words there are ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Amazing @anubhava... thank you so much. I have to ask though, what resources/references do you use to get that good ? I've been struggling to get any better than I am now for a while, I just don't know what to read or watch or what to practice on...

Comment: I have found https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html pretty good reference for learning regex

Comment: also: https://regex101.com/r/zw09w4/1

Answer (score 1):

Can run another regex in the replacement side, under `/e` modifier

```perl
$string =~ s{.+?\..+?\.(.+?)\.ext$}{ $1 =~ s/-/ /gr }e;
```

The regex inside the replacement side has to use `/r` modifier since `$1` can't be changed.

---

*Comment on edit of the question and tags*

This answer was posted on the version of the question which had `perl` tag.  This is still a one-regex way of doing what is asked but it uses Perl syntax in the replacement side.

(It turns out that the original post in fact had no `perl` tag, which was then added by someone other than the author -- what I answered -- who then removed it.  I didn't know any of this.)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `-` with spaces using `s/\-/ /g`

```perl
my $string = "word1.word2.worda-wordb-wordc.ext";

$string =~ s/.+?\..+?\.(.+?)\.ext$/$1/;
$string =~ s/\-/ /g;

print($string);  # worda wordb wordc
```

Answer (score 0):

Desired result can be achieved in several ways:

1. utilizing [regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) as in your example
2. [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) the string on `.`

   - take 3-rd part
   - replace `-` with

Demonstration code provided bellow

- `regex` method is commented out
- `split` method used by code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = 'word1.word2.worda-wordb-wordc.ext';

#$str =~ s!\w+\.\w+\.(.*?)\.ext!$1 =~ s/-/ /gr!e;
$str = (split('\.',$str))[2] =~ s/-/ /gr;

say $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

- regex: `\w+\K-()|(?<=-)\w+\K|.`
- substitution: `${1:+ }`

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/ljl1P3/1)